# AJAX doesn't change my JSP dynamically?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, servlets

What is wrong with this AJAX code of mine? It should change the state of the button to enabled or disabled based on the conditions.

```
function loadXML(){
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            /* alert (xmlhttp.responseText); */
            if(xmlhttp.responseText == true) {
                document.getElementById('scan').disabled=false;
                document.getElementById('secret').value = "true";
            }
            else if(xmlhttp.responseText == false){
                document.getElementById('scan').disabled=true;
                document.getElementById('secret').value = "false";
            }  
        }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "ScanJobServlet", true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

setInterval("loadXML()", 5000 );
```

This function is being executed every 5 seconds to check if there are changes in the response of the servlet.

Here is my Servlet: it has an event listener that when I plug the USB the response becomes true and if I unplugged the usb, the response becomes false.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //super.doGet(req, resp);       

    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();

    RemovableStorageEventListener listener = new RemovableStorageEventListener() 
    { 
        public void inserted(Storage storage) {
            status = true;
    }
        public void removed(Storage storage) {
            status = false;
        } 
    }; 

    BundleContext bc = AppManager.getInstance().getBundleContext();
    StorageManager sm = StorageManager.getInstance(KSFUtility.getInstance().getApplicationContext(bc));
    sm.addListener(listener);

    if (status==true)
    {
        out.print("true");
    }
    else
    {
        out.print("false");
    }

}
```

Comment: 1) What is the value alert showing up? 2) Do you have Element with ID 'scan' and 'secret'?

Comment: I got the code working already but I have a question...

will AJAX continue to go inside 'if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)' everytime the event listener is triggered in the servlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code,

```
if (status==true)
  {
    out.print("true");
  }
else
  {
    out.print("false");
  }
```

You are returning the literal `"true"` and `"false"`. Try using `true` and `false` without quotes.
In JavaScript, `"true"` and `"false"` differ from `true` and `false`, because double quotes indicate a literal. Updated:

```
if (status==true)
  {
    out.print(true);
  }
else
  {
    out.print(false);
  }
```

Comment: thanks...I have another question...will the AJAX code continue to go inside the 'if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)' everytime the event listener is activated?

Comment: @pmark019 It should, since you added an event listener, it should activate every time it is ready, just how `onclick` runs a function as many times as clicked.

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript code, try this:

```
(xmlhttp.responseText == "true")
```

instead of

```
(xmlhttp.responseText == true)
```

same for **(xmlhttp.responseText == false)** , change it for **(xmlhttp.responseText == "false")** (with quotes)